# How to combine two json array in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two json arrays with the same length.

e.g

**First:**

```
[
  0: {name: "name1", id:"1"},
  1: {name: "name2", id:"2"},
  2: {name: "name3", id:"3"},
]
```

**Second:**

```
[
  0: {surname: "surname1"},
  1: {surname: "surname2"},
  2: {surname: "surname3"},
]
```

**Expected resoult**

```
[
  0: {name: "name1", id:"1", surname: "surname1"},
  1: {name: "name2", id:"2", surname: "surname2"},
  2: {name: "name3", id:"3", surname: "surname3"},
]
```

How to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` function to iterate over the first one and getting appropriate index you can get `surname` from the second array and concat them

```js
const arr1 = [
  { name: "name1", id:"1" },
  { name: "name2", id:"2" },
  { name: "name3", id:"3" }
];
  
const arr2 = [
  { surname: "surname1" },
  { surname: "surname2" },
  { surname: "surname3" }
];
  
const newArr = arr1.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, surname: arr2[index].surname}));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lodash` library [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge) function:

`var merge = _.merge(arr1, arr2);`